# 'DataFrame' object is not callable in recommender system

Tags: python, dataframe, recommendation-engine

This is my code

```
def get_recommendations(title, cosine_sim=cosine_sim):
# Get the index of the movie that matches the title
idx = indices[title]

# Get the pairwsie similarity scores of all movies with that movie
sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[idx]))

# Sort the movies based on the similarity scores
sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

# Get the scores of the 10 most similar movies
sim_scores = sim_scores[1:6]

# Get the movie indices
movie_indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]

# Return the top 10 most similar movies
return metadata(['title'],['desc']).iloc[movie_indices]
get_recommendations('The Dark Knight')
```

I am getting this error which is TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 get_recommendations('The Dark Knight')

in get_recommendations(title, cosine_sim)
16
17     # Return the top 10 most similar movies
---> 18     return metadata(['title'],['desc']).iloc[movie_indices]

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

Change the brackets

```
return metadata[['title','desc']].iloc[movie_indices]
```